# Can't jump or call kernel loaded at 0x8000

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I am trying to develop an operating system. The design is this: I have a bootloader loaded at 0x7c00 which loads the second stage and jumps to it at 0x7e00. The second stage is also in real mode and does a lot of stuff such as loading gdt, enabling A20 and switching to protected mode. It also loads a very simple 32 bit kernel at 0x8000. The problem now is that I am not able to call or jmp to 0x8000 as the kernel doesn't seem to get loaded(I did a memory dump in *VirtualBox*). I have already done a *FAR JMP* within the second stage to set the *CS* register.  I am testing my OS in *VirtualBox*.

Code for my boot loader:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
Start:
      jmp Reset
      bpbOEM DB "SKULLOS " 
      bpbBytesPerSector:    DW 512
      bpbSectorsPerCluster:     DB 1
      bpbReservedSectors:   DW 1
      bpbNumberOfFATs:      DB 2
      bpbRootEntries:       DW 224
      bpbTotalSectors:      DW 2880
      bpbMedia:                 DB 0xF0
      bpbSectorsPerFAT:         DW 9
      bpbSectorsPerTrack:   DW 18
      bpbHeadsPerCylinder:  DW 2
      bpbHiddenSectors:         DD 0
      bpbTotalSectorsBig:     DD 0
      bsDriveNumber:            DB 0
      bsUnused:                 DB 0
      bsExtBootSignature:   DB 0x29
      bsSerialNumber:           DD 0xa0a1a2a3
      bsVolumeLabel:            DB "MOS FLOPPY "
      bsFileSystem:             DB "SKFS    "
Set:
      mov al , 02h
      mov ah , 00h
      int 10h
      jmp Print
Print:
      mov al , 'A'
      mov bl , 0Fh
      mov cx , 01h
      mov ah , 09h
      int 10h
      jmp Reset
Reset:
      ; mov dl , 0x00
        mov [0x500] , dl
        mov ah , 0x00
        int 0x13
        jc Reset
        mov ax , 0x7E0 
        mov es , ax
        xor bx , bx
        mov ah , 0x02
        mov al , 1
        mov ch , 0
        mov cl , 2
        mov dh , 0
        mov dl , [0x500]
        int 0x13
        jmp 0x0000 :0x7e00
        times 510-($-$$) db 0
        db 0x55
        db 0xAA
```

Code for second stage:

```
    org 0x7E00
    bits 16
    Start:
          jmp Setup
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;stack;;;;;;;;;;
    Setup: 
          cli
          xor ax , ax
          mov ds , ax
          mov es , ax
          mov ax , 0x9000
          mov ss , ax
          mov sp , 0xFFFF
          sti
          jmp Set
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;video;;;;;;;;;;;
   Set: 
          mov al , 03h
          mov ah , 00h
          int 10h
          mov ah , 09h
          mov al , 'A'
          mov bh , 00h
          mov bl , 0x0F
          mov cx , 01h
          int 10h
          jmp loadgdt
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;gdt;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   gdt_start:
   null: 
          dd 0
          dd 0
   code:
          dw 0FFFFh
          dw 0
          db 0
          db 10011010b
          db 11001111b
          db 0
   data:
          dw 0FFFFh
          dw 0
          db 0
          db 10010010b
          db 11001111b
          db 0
   end:
   load: dw end - gdt_start -1
         dd null
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;loadgdt;;;;;;;;;;
   loadgdt:
         lgdt [load]
         jmp A20
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;A20;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   A20:
         mov ax , 0x2401
         int 0x15
         jc A20
         jmp Reset
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;floppy;;;;;;;;;;;
   Reset:
         mov ah , 00h
         mov dl , [0x500]
         int 13h
         jc Reset
         jmp Read
   Read:
         mov ah , 02h
         mov al , 01h
         mov ch , 00h
         mov cl , 03h
         mov dh , 00h
         mov dl , [0x500]
         mov ax , 0x800
         mov es , ax
         xor bx , bx
         int 13h
         jc Read
         jmp Begin
   Begin:  
         mov ah , 09h
         mov al , 'G'
         mov bh , 00h
         mov bl , 0x0F
         mov cx , 01h
         int 10h
         jmp protected
   ;;;;;;;;;;;switching to protected;;;;
   protected: 
             mov ah , 09h
             mov al , 'P'
             mov bh , 00h
             mov bl , 0x0F
             mov cx , 01h
             int 10h
             xor ax, ax
             mov ds, ax    
             cli
             mov eax, cr0
             or eax , 1
             mov cr0 , eax
             jmp (code-gdt_start):transfer_control
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   bits 32 
   transfer_control:
                    mov ax, (data-gdt_start)        
                    mov ds, ax
                    mov ss, ax
                    mov es, ax
                    mov esp, 90000h
                    mov [0xB8000], word 0x0F58  ; Print 'X' 
                    call 0x8000    
                    hlt
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Code for kernel:

```
org 0x8000
bits 32
jmp Start
Start:
      mov ax , 0x10
      mov ds , ax
      mov ss, ax
      mov es, ax
      mov esp, 90000h
      mov [0xB8002], word 0x0F58   ; Print 'X'
      ret
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Currently, only one 'X' is being printed. However, two 'X' should be printed.
Commands used to create floppy:

```
      dd seek=0 if=boot of=os.img
      dd seek=1 if=second_stage of=os.img
      dd seek=2 if=third_stage of=os.img
```

[image: OS running in virtualbox]

Comment: Is the lgdt correct? Where is the gdt linear address specified?

Comment: I modified my code and did not set the dl register. I added  mov [0x500] , dl to my load function in the first stage. Moreover, I added mov dl , [0x500] instead of mov dl , 00h

Comment: I use dd to create the floppy image. I used a hex editor and it shows that there is no problem with the disk image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem Reading Stage 3

In the second stage you load the third stage doing this:

```
   Read:
         mov ah , 02h      ; Setup AH
         mov al , 01h      ; Setup AL
         mov ch , 00h
         mov cl , 03h
         mov dh , 00h
         mov dl , [0x500]
         mov ax , 0x800    ; Destroy contents of AX 
         mov es , ax       ; Setup ES=0x800
         xor bx , bx
         int 13h
```

I have marked the lines with the problems. You effectively set up *AX* to get ready for the read and then overwrite the values with 0x800 to set up *ES*. Move setting up *ES* before you setup *AH* and *AL*. Modify the code to look like:

```
   Read:
         mov ax , 0x800 
         mov es , ax       ; Setup ES=0x800
         mov ah , 02h      ; Setup AH
         mov al , 01h      ; Setup AL
         mov ch , 00h
         mov cl , 03h
         mov dh , 00h
         mov dl , [0x500]
         xor bx , bx
         int 13h
```

This likely prevents your second stage from loading the 3rd stage properly.

---

### Other Issues

At the end of the bootloader you have:

```
    db 0xAA
    db 0x55
```

This is backwards and should be:

```
    db 0x55
    db 0xAA
```

You could have written it as:

```
    dw 0xAA55
```

The issue appears to be that you didn't take little endianness into account when defining these bytes.

---

You properly jump over the BIOS Parameter Block in the bootloader, but the BPB needs to start at the 4th byte in the boot sector. You can force a 2-byte JMP using the `short` modifier. You can then place a `nop` after the jump so that the BPB starts at the 4th byte.

Change:

```
  jmp Reset
  bpbOEM DB "SKULLOS "
```

To:

```
  jmp short Reset
  nop         ; 1 byte padding as BPB needs to start at 4th byte (short jmp takes 2 bytes)
  bpbOEM DB "SKULLOS "
```

---

`mov sp , 0xFFFF` should probably be `mov sp, 0x0000`. This is just a minor nitpick. Having the stack on a *WORD* boundary (even addresses) performs better on 8086 processors. Since you are not in real mode very long it doesn't much matter at all. Usually you'd use `mov sp, 0x0000` in your case because the first *WORD* pushed will be at 0x9000:0xfffe since 2 is subtracted from SP first and then the *WORD* pushed onto the stack. Effectively with SP=0x0000 the stack will start by wrapping to the top of the 64k segment.

---

You don't need to *JMP* from label to label if the label is right after the *JMP*. Instructions like:

```
    jmp Set 
Set:
```

does nothing but waste space and take CPU cycles. I noticed you did that in quite a few places. This isn't part of your problem, just an observation. The *FAR JUMP* `jmp (code-gdt_start):transfer_control` followed by the label is fine since that is used to to set the CS descriptor properly (for protected mode)

---

When doing disk access with `int 13h` you should be using the boot drive number passed by the BIOS to your bootloader as the value for *DL*. Your first and second stages have code like:

```
mov dl , 00h
```

This always assumes you are reading from the first floppy (*A:*). If you want to use your code on a boot drive other than Floppy *A:* you'll want to remove this

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I now understand that the second stage didn't load the third stage properly because I didn't set the registers in order. I will stop jumping from label to label unnecessarily from now on.

Comment: "The `jmp Reset` instruction is only 3 bytes long." -- It is (due to optimisation) a short jump that is only 2 bytes long, necessitating the `nop` as the 3rd byte so the pseudo-BPB starts in the 4th byte. As in the other answer, you should make the `jmp short` explicit and add the `nop`.

Comment: I just realized this isn't the same question as the last one @ecm. I'll edit this when I'm home.

Comment: @Michael Petch: Seems like you have forgotten this, so here's a reminder.

Comment: @Michael Petch: You still haven't updated the running text which reads "The `jmp Reset` instruction is only 3 bytes long. You can place a nop after the jump so that the BPB starts at the 4th byte."